# NHibernate gets stuck repeating the same query over and over

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I can't understand what is happening here. It gets into a loop when I try to fetch some results using NHibernate.

I have the following two domain objects, mapped in NHibernate.

```
public class Orden
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Lanzamiento Lanzamiento { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime FechaOrden { get; set; }
    public virtual IArticulo Articulo { get; set; }
    public virtual double Cantidad { get; set; }
    public virtual int IdEstado { get; set; }
    public virtual string Observaciones { get; set; }
    public virtual Lote Lote { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<OrdenBono> Bonos { get; set; }
}

public class OrdenBono
{
    public virtual Orden Orden { get; set; }
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<OrdenBonoEntrada> Entradas { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<OrdenBonoSalida> Salidas { get; set; }
    public virtual int IdEstado { get; set; }
    public virtual Maquina Maquina { get; set; }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        OrdenBono u = obj as OrdenBono;
        if (u == null) return false;
        return u.Orden == Orden && u.Id == Id;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 13;
        hash = hash * 7 + Orden.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 7 + Id.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Nothing fancy there. Then I'm querying some of those by the following code:

```
public IQueryOver<Orden, Orden> QueryOrdenesPorMaquina(Maquina m)
    {
        ISession session = NHibernateHelper.GetSession();
        session.BeginTransaction();
        return session.QueryOver<Orden>()
                .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(o => o.Id)
                .In(
                QueryOver.Of<OrdenBono>()
                .Where(ob => ob.Maquina == m)
                .Select(ob => ob.Orden.Id)
                );
    }
    public IQueryOver<Orden> QueryOrdenesSinFinalizarEnvasadoPorMaquina(Maquina m)
    { 
            return QueryOrdenesPorMaquina(m)
             .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(o => o.Id).In(
                QueryOver.Of<OrdenBono>()
                .Where(ob => ob.Descripcion.IsLike("Prod%") && ob.IdEstado == 2)
                .JoinQueryOver(ob => ob.Orden)
                .JoinQueryOver<OrdenBono>(o2 => o2.Bonos)
                .Where(ob => ob.Descripcion.IsLike("Env%") && ob.IdEstado < 2)
                .Select(ob => ob.Orden.Id)
                );
    }
    public IEnumerable<Orden> ObtenerOrdenesPorMaquina(Maquina m)
    {
        return QueryOrdenesPorMaquina(m).List();
    }
    public IEnumerable<Orden> OrdenesSinFinalizarEnvasadoPorMaquina(Maquina m)
    {
        return QueryOrdenesSinFinalizarEnvasadoPorMaquina(m).List();
    }
    public int NumeroOrdenesSinFinalizarEnvasadoPorMaquina(Maquina m)
    {
        return QueryOrdenesSinFinalizarEnvasadoPorMaquina(m).RowCount();
    }
```

When I call `OrdenesSinFinalizarEnvasadoPorMaquina` it does the first query OK, but then it gets into a loop repeating the same query over and over, and I don't understand why!

If I call the `RowCount()`one it works just fine and returns `3`, but the `IEnumerable` just doesn't work. This is the output from the console of the first line, which I can see it's correct and gets the data I'm looking for:

[image: Correct]

But then it keeps repeating over and over the following query:

```
NHibernate: SELECT orden0_.IdOrden as IdOrd1_15_1_, orden0_.FechaOrden as Fecha2_15_1_, orden0_.IdArticulo as IdArt3_15_1_, orden0_.Cantidad as Canti4_15_1_, orden0_.Observaciones as Obser5_15_1_, orden0_.IdEstado as IdEst6_15_1_, orden0_.IdLanzamiento as IdLan7_15_1_, orden0_.Lote as Lote8_15_1_, bonos1_.IdOrden as IdOrd1_16_3_, bonos1_.IdBono as IdBon2_16_3_, bonos1_.IdOrden as IdOrd1_16_0_, bonos1_.IdBono as IdBon2_16_0_, bonos1_.Descrip as Descr3_16_0_, bonos1_.IdEstado as IdEst4_16_0_, bonos1_.Matricula as Matri5_16_0_ FROM Ordenes orden0_ left outer join Ordenes_Bonos bonos1_ on orden0_.IdOrden=bonos1_.IdOrden WHERE orden0_.IdOrden=@p0;@p0 = 97857 [Type: Int32 (0:0:0)]
```

As you can see here:

[image: Loop]

Answer (score 0):

Can you publish the call / usage of "ObtenerOrdenesPorMaquina(x)"

some what like i quess:

```
foreach(var x in ObtenerOrdenesPorMaquina(y))
{
}
```

you may suffer a multiple enumeration issue.

how does your query behave if you use

```
var allObtenereOrdersOfMaquinaY = ObtenerOrdenesPorMaquina(y).ToList();  
foreach(var x in allObtenereOrdersOfMaquinaY)
{
}
```

you most likely wan't to consider returning a ReadOnlyCollection or List over a IEnumerable from your query. Since there won't be a use-case to enumerate over a sql-query, but the populated list instead. the enumeration introduces the complexity that you don't know when the query will be executed. maybe even after you closed the db session.